# Tiny mouse pointer with Libreoffice snap

Tags: mouse, libreoffice

I installed Libreoffice snap and it works, but the mouse pointer is tiny, almost unusably so, while over the Libreoffice windows.

Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13.

Background info: I needed a newer version of Libreoffice than 18.04 came with, so I went to "Ubuntu Software" and installed Libreoffice...I now have both the original version 6.0.3.2 which still works fine, and the snap 6.0.4.2 which has the mouse pointer problem.

Comment: If you want a newer version than is supplied with 18.04, consider using this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. You won't have any mouse pointer issues with it and the ppa version will respect your theme as well. Snaps, as of now, are a bit inflexible.

Comment: Thanks have done that now and removed the snap version. Would still be nice to know why and how to fix though...

Comment: You can install multiple versions by downloading a gzipped tar file of the version of your choice from the libreoffice website.You can then use the version of your choice by giving the absolute path to the executable or by using version-qualified symlinks .  You can even build from source. We are not limited to the package management systems.

Comment: Re. getting snaps to use user's GTK themes, mouse cursor themes, etc. please see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/use-the-system-gtk-theme/496 and https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/improvements-in-the-content-interface/2387. TLDR: work in progress.

Comment: I see, thanks, not just a simple config problem then!

Answer (score 0):

Installing from the PPA as @DKBose's comment and removing the snap version means I now only have one copy of libreoffice installed and it is the later version that I needed, and avoids the tiny mouse pointer problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Libreoffice flatpak 7.3.2.2
These terminal commands fixed it. You can fix other apps by replacing the name at end, letter for letter correctly. For example you could fix Spotify by adding... com.spotify.Client ...to the end of command.

```
sudo flatpak override --env=XCURSOR_THEME=DMZ-White org.libreoffice.LibreOffice

sudo flatpak override --env=XCURSOR_SIZE=72 org.libreoffice.LibreOffice
```